# Do I need a visa to travel to Victoria from Seattle by ferry?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, ferries

I am British and I have an ESTA to enter Seattle, USA from the UK. Do I need a visa to travel to Victoria, Canada from Seattle by ferry?

Comment: Hmm, this question appears to be in the opposite direction of @gerrit's proposed duplicate. The OP wants to enter _Canada_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh, I misread.  The ESTA put me off.  I'm 99.9% sure the answer is "no", though.  But maybe Julie needs eTA.

Answer (score 4):

Citizens of the United Kingdom do not need a visa to enter Canada.

If you arrive in Canada *by air* you would need to have an Electronic Travel Authorization, but since you're taking a ferry rather than a plane, carrying your British passport should be sufficient.

---

If you're not going back to the US from Canada after your visit, you may get some trouble because you may not be registered as having left the US when you leave by surface transport. Therefore when you enter the US *later* you may be suspected of having overstayed, and you should be traveling with documentation that you did in fact leave the US when you did. An entry stamp from Canada may do the trick, but other documentation of continuing a life outside the US will be helpful too.

Comment: To ensure that your departure from the US is recorded correctly, see this question & answer:  [How can I ensure my exit from the US by land is recorded?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93520/how-can-i-ensure-my-exit-from-the-us-by-land-is-recorded)