# If a person's passport is not stamped upon leaving the U.S., will returning be a problem?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, israeli-citizens

If an Israeli citizen's passport was not stamped upon leaving the U.S. will she have a problem return to the United States?

Comment: The US does not examine or stamp anyone’s passport on leaving.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question itself is based on an erroneous premise.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus That's not the way off-topic votes are designed to be used.  If the premise of the question is not accurate, you should provide an answer to the question.  [Please read the Be Nice policy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: Here is a related question about how to ensure that the US records your exit correctly: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93520/how-can-i-ensure-my-exit-from-the-us-by-land-is-recorded

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk I think it depends on what the false premise is. In this case, I agree that correcting the false premise is a valuable answer; in cases where the false premise renders the question nonsensical, I think we should close.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk Additionally, a question based upon a false premise might also be deemed not very useful and get downvoted. In this case, I'm not sure it's a useful question here. It may depend on how often this actually is a problem in practice.

Comment: I can't see how this question is supposed to be based on a false premise. The question is based on not knowing the correct answer, which is what most questions are like.

Answer (score 37):

The US does not stamp any passport on exit of the country.
All officials know this so it will not be a problem.

Most likely your exit has been recorded; you can [check that online](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search) these days.

[This question and answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93520/how-can-i-ensure-my-exit-from-the-us-by-land-is-recorded) explain it for a land exit but it works for air exits as well.

Answer (score 4):

Me as a German, I entered and left the US dozens of times over the years and never got an exit stamp. Authorities know by the airline database that you left... so, no stamps on leaving... at least in the US. Most other countries do though.

Comment: "Most other countries do"... sure about that? I've been traveling in 30+ countries around europe and never had my passport stamped there.

Comment: @eis Yes, most countries stamp foreigners in and out. The main exceptions are the UK, the US, Ireland, Canada, Mexico (some exits), and Australia (some travellers). In Europe, non-EEA citizens will be stamped in and out when they enter or leave the Schengen zone. I think this still leaves 100+ countries which stamp people in and out systematically.

Comment: @eis: If you are an EU citizen, of course you do not get stamped on entry on exit (so I can't really say whether or not you get stamped on exit when you are not an EU citizen). In my passport, the USA and Mexico do not have exit stamps (but they do have entry stamps).

Answer (score -3):

It has been said already that when leaving by air, the US does not stamp passports. When you check in, the airline takes the stub of the form you filled out when entering the US, and which usually gets stapled to the page of the passport where the entry stamp was placed.

Sometimes, things get messed up, and your exit is not properly recorded. In this case, it can be very helpful to keep the boarding pass of the flight leaving the US, and have it ready if needed.

Comment: I doubt they will tell me that my exit was not properly recorded. So you are saying I should keep all boarding passes forever?

Comment: Outdated. The paper stubs do no longer exist, since many years.

Comment: The paper I94-W form for air travel was discontinued in 2013.

Comment: @gnasher729 Obviously, my info is dated, but it would have been sufficient to keep the boarding pass from the last flight out of the US.

Comment: @MaxWyss Having the boarding pass might help CBP to correct the records if there was an inconsistency (since it'll include the flight information), but just having the flight information would serve as well. After all, a boarding pass doesn't prove that you actually took the flight.