# I traveled to the USA with an ESTA and left after 30 days but it is showing that I am still in the USA

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, i-94

I have left the USA but just got an email that saying I have not left. I also checked the https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/ and it shows that I am still in the USA. Also checked my British passport and it was not stamped on my way out.

I traveled in on the Oct 1 and left 30th.

Comment: Nothing to panic about. You are not the first nor will you be the last. Follow the process for [the answers in this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93520/how-can-i-ensure-my-exit-from-the-us-by-land-is-recorded/93523#93523). You may also wait for another month or so to see if perhaps the i94 gets updated. Sometimes some of these databases take a while to be updated.

Comment: Alternatively Send CBP an email from this site: https://help.cbp.gov/app/ask stating that your latest online I-94 is incorrect. They usually respond in a day (or hours!) asking for you to email a scan of the biographic page, visa page and the entry stamp page of the passport of the traveler. After they receive it, and another day or so they will respond saying that they corrected the issue. The online system will then start showing you the accurate I-94 record.

Comment: You are a super star !!!! I was so worried. Thank you and will send the email now.

Comment: Passports are never stamped on the way out of the US, so that is something else you don't need to worry about. They normally get notice of your departure from the airline.  (Did you leave the US by land?)

Comment: If you still have it, hang on to your boarding pass from when you departed the US (or if you left by land, to something that shows you left, including a boarding pass from Canada or Mexico). If you ever get any questions about whether you left on time, you'll have something to show that you did.

Comment: I’m surprised by the e-mail alert. Is that something that is actually done nowadays?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.